# z-index: position child below container

Tags: css, css-position

`z-index: -1` for the `:before` is not working when specifying `z-index:2` for the box.

How to move the `:before` below the box keeping the `z-index:2` for the box.

```css
.box{
  background: lavender;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.box:before{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gLnfde49/

Comment: first duplicate to explain the issue, second one to give an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  background: lavender;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.main
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50;
  transform : translate(50%,50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
</div>
</div>
```

I have **achieved** this using the `::before` element and used the main element as `position:relative;`.
To make the div of class `.box` to be in middle of the page add a div above (`.main`) if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is with `transform` property and you need to `relative` parent for `absolute` child

```
.box {
    background: lavender;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translateX(-50%); */
    /* z-index: 2; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```